# Redefine active character `~` in expl3

Tags: expl3, active-characters

Is there any way to redefine the tilde (`~`) active character in expl3 syntax? In expl2, I would simply do something like `\let~\relax`, but due to the interpretation of `~` in expl3, this is not possible.

Comment: Usually it's char_set_active_eq...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a meaning to an active character is done with

```
\char_set_active_eq:NN
```

or

```
\char_set_active_eq:nN
```

You can't use the first, which wants the exact character as its first argument. But the second one wants the character's ASCII/Unicode code and the normal conventions of TeX apply, so you can escape a character with a backslash in the context of alphabetic constants.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\char_set_active_eq:nN { `\~ } \scan_stop:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some text~some more text

\end{document}
```

[image]

In general, you'd define your own command and use that instead of `\scan_stop:` (*aka* `\relax`).

Comment: Thank you, this looks like what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You want `\char_set_active_eq:NN` plus need to make `~` into something other than a space while 'working' with it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\char_set_catcode_other:N \~
\cs_new_protected:Npn \noldorin_demo: { !!! }
\char_set_active_eq:NN ~ \noldorin_demo:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Some text~some more text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any substantive diference between this and @egreg's solution?